# Find formula for linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^3 $ and $\ker T= span((1,1,1,1),(1,1,1,0))$ and $image T=span((1,1,1),(1,1,0))$ find formula for T if exists.

I think it will exists since dimentions are good, but I have problem with finding formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the two given vector of $\ker T$ by $e_1,e_1$ and let $B=(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4)$ a basis of $\Bbb R^4$.  Denote the two given vector of the image of $T$ by $v_1,v_2$ and let $B'=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ a basis of $\Bbb R^3$. Define $T$ as follow:

$$T(e_1)=T(e_2)=0\quad;\quad T(e_3)=v_1\quad;\quad T(e_4)=v_2$$
and the matrix of $T$ relative to the basis $B$ and $B'$ is

$$[T]_{B\to B'}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
Now write the matrix of $T$ relative to the standard basis using the change matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1) $\{(1,1,1,1),(1,1,1,0),(1,1,0,0),(1,0,0,0)\}$ forms a basis of $\mathbb{R^4}$.

2) The first two basis vectors get sent to the $0$ vector.

3) Image of $(1,1,0,0)$ is a linear combination of $(1,1,1)$ and $(1,1,0)$.

4) Image of $(1,0,0,0)$ is a linear combination of $(1,1,1)$ and $(1,1,0)$.